# Android in-app payment for physical items, where to store price information?

Tags: java, android, paypal, in-app-purchase

I am working on a Android app with the possibility to purchase a physical items. The payment will be implemented with help of the Paypal SDK.
Now i am facing a problem. I only offer two products which can be ordered. First one for say 10 Euro and the second one for 15 Euro. 
Where do I have to place the price information which is then to be transfered to Paypal? I don´t think hardcoding the price for my items
into the app is a good approach, but I did not find any better solution for it. I decompiled the app of one competitioner and saw that he also just saves the
price into the app?

Once i hardcode the price information into the app, how should I change it in future? Old app installations will always have
the old price? Lets say it was 10 Euro and now it should be 12 Euro?! How should I change that?
One possibility would be to get the price informaton from my CloudService each time the user starts my app?

What are other solutions for that problem? I want to be flexibel to change the price of my products and to be safe from manipulation.
(I would verifiy the payment with my CloudService and Paypal)

Regards

Comment: I would store the products. price on the server. Retrieve it from the server to the app. in that way u can add new products, price in the future.

Comment: I am not sure how you are doing using Paypal, did you implement Android Inapp Purchases to purchase an item?

Comment: Paypal SDK is just there for the payment. The order process is way more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store price on your Server this is the best way

Comment: Ok, i think this will be the best advice. Next problem will be to implement custom api call to my mobile service in the azure cloud. Could not get this to work since 2 days. There is no documentation on how to do custom api calls to mobile service from android client. No one that works.

Answer (score 0):

You set pricing in Google Play Console.

Go to your application, Store presence, In-app products.

You can add your products and pricing info in there.